# Code Working in VB 2013 And Not Working in VB 2019?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a code which is working very well in VB.Net 2013 and the same code (Copy & Paste) is not working in VB.Net 2019?

I receive error

> Invalid Index (Exception from HRESULT: 0X8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

The Error only shows with this Line

```vb
Destination = CType(wb.Sheets(Diameter), Excel.Worksheet)
```

`wb` is a `Workbook`.
`Destination` is a variable holding new worksheets (`Worksheet`).
`Diameter` is a variable holding new worksheets names (`String`).

I wonder why it is working in 2013 and not working in 2019.

Comment: Are you sure there is a sheet with that name in that workbook?

Comment: Maybe `Destination = CType(wb.Sheets(Diameter - 1), Excel.Worksheet)`